# Need help understanding Typeerror

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I am getting "TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not builtin_function_or_method" and don't really understand how to fix it as I am checking if the guessed letter is appearing in the word.

Just need to know the best other route to do it.

```
import random
wordlist = ['python','hangman','hippopotamus','eschscholtzia']
word = random.choice(wordlist)

answer = word[0:30]
display = []
display.extend(answer)
for i in range(len(answer)):
    display[i] = '_'

print('Welcome to hangman, type quit to exit program.')
print('the word has', len(word), 'letters')
print(display)
guess = input('pick a letter? ')
guess = guess.lower

for i in range(len(answer)):
    if display[i] == guess:
        display[i] = guess

while guess != 'quit':
guessedletters = []
guessedletters.append(guess)
if guess in word:
    print('Well Done it has',word.count(guess),guess)
else:
    print('sorry no',guess,'in the word')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the `guess = guess.lower` problem that @wertie8297 nicely explains (+1), your code has other issues.  For example, this code:

```
for i in range(len(answer)):
    if display[i] == guess:
        display[i] = guess
```

appears to do nothing.  Also your indentation is incorrect and your pick a letter logic is outside (before) your loop so the game will never play. Here's a rework of your code that addresses some of these issues and attempts to make a playable game:

```
from random import choice

WORD_LIST = ['python', 'hangman', 'hippopotamus', 'eschscholtzia']

word = choice(WORD_LIST)

print("Welcome to hangman, type 'quit' to exit program.")
print("The word has", len(word), "letters.")

display = ['_' for _ in word]

guessed_correct_letters = set()

while True:
    print(*display)

    guess = input("pick a letter: ")
    guess = guess.lower()

    if guess == 'quit':
        break
    if guess in guessed_correct_letters:
        print("You already found", guess, "in the word")
    elif guess in word:
        guessed_correct_letters.add(guess)

        print("Well Done, it has", word.count(guess), guess)

        display = [letter if letter in guessed_correct_letters else '_' for letter in word]

        if '_' not in display:
            print("Congratulations, you solved it!")
            break
    else:
        print("Sorry, no", guess, "in the word")
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call .lower() with guess = guess.lower, you're just referring to the method 'lower' not actually calling it

If you change that line to

```
guess.lower()
```

Then it should fix your problem

The exception is being raised because you're trying to see if the method 'lower' is in a word, rather than the string which would be returned if you were calling the method instead

Answer (score 0):

Where it says `guess = guess.lower`.

`lower()` is a *function*, giving it without the call gives this weird metadata like `<__main__:lower object at 0x12345678>`

the fixed code is `guess = guess.lower()`